# Shortcut for instantiating an Excel object?

Tags: c#, excel

I see the following in the declarations section at the top of a .cs file. I assume it's a shortcut for instantaiting the Excel object?

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I could just have the following and then instantiate Excel later on?

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the Excel namespace, but not a shortcut for the Excel application object. For example, if you have two namespaces declaring the same class `Location` you can use a namespace alias to prevent [name clashes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/10/20/245297.aspx):

```
using MyProject.Model;
using Maps = Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;

var location = new Location(); // MyProject.Model.Location
var location2 = new Maps.Location(); // Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Location
```

Comment: ok - so conversely if there aren't going to be any name clashes then it's not required?

Answer (score 0):

No, using `using` directive that way will not instantiate anything. It's just a way to give an alias to a specified class, which is useful in case of conflicting class names.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) for more details.